# SAN for nullmove?

Tags: engines, notation, uci

The long algebraic notation (lan) for null move is usually 00-00 or simply 0000. Chess engines that support the nullmove: "give up a turn, and let the other side move" typically use this as its part of UCI. What  would the SAN representation be?

Comment: Actually, I'm not even aware there is such thing as nullmove in SAN. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing 00 similar to pawn move d4

Answer (score 3):

Νικόλαος Μανωλακος asked:

> What would the SAN representation [*of a null move*] be?

Several possibilities present themselves as to what the SAN notation can be, but *none* that I have found claim to be *the official* standard specification for SAN. The following results indicate within the quotation marks the annotation used (intended to be used without the quotation marks).

**NAG (Numeric Annotation Glyph) "$0"**
     *IAW art. 10, table 1, line 1 [ref. 1, 2, 3]*

**PGN's SAN:  "--"**
     *[ref. 4, 5, 6, 7]*
     *Note:  In ref. 7, null moves start out as mere comments, and can become [null] moves, but it's unclear as to whether they necessarily become so.*

**PGN's SAN:  "@@@@"**
     *[ref. 8]*

**"<>", "--"**
     *[ref. 9]*
     *Note:  "A Null Move acts as a placeholder for an expected move that is not played."*

**"pass", "null", "@@@@"**
     *[ref. 10]*

**Stockfish's SAN:  "null"**
     *[ref. 11]*

**"(null)"**
     *[ref. 12]*

---

**References:**

1. http://www.saremba.de/chessgml/standards/pgn/pgn-complete.htm#c10
2. https://www.chessclub.com/user/help/PGN-spec
3. https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Games-Chess/lib/Games/Chess/PGN.pod#NUMERIC-ANNOTATION-GLYPHS
4. https://github.com/k2052/chess.rb/blob/master/lib/chess/san.rb
5. https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/help.html#portability
6. https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/whats_new/4.6.0/#tag-D6
7. http://www.triplehappy.com/faq.html
8. https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/engine-intf.html#8
9. http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/palview/manual/pgn.htm#pgncontnull
10. http://hgm.nubati.net/alien.html
11. https://github.com/mcostalba/FishCooking/blob/master/src/notation.cpp
12. https://github.com/erashid/DON/blob/master/src/Notation.cpp